# Is this a bug or what? Editor became the author of the question?

Tags: support

I was looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-bash-shell-script) when I realized that there is something very strange: the user Grundlefleck apparently posted this question on Sep 12 '08 at 20:06 and then it seems he answered to his own question the very next minute on Sep 12 '08 at 20:07.

My question is: is this a bug?

Reading the tone of the answer, it seems to me that Grundlefleck thinks to talk to someone else, it doesn't seem to me he's answering to his own question.
Maybe he edited the question and then he answered the very next minute, and for some reason the site shows him in place of the original author of the question.

Comment: [The OP answered you in the comments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-bash-shell-script#comment12781305_59839), just a few minutes ago.

Comment: Could be intentional; answering your own questions is encouraged (although there's some debate about whether answering your own question right after posting is bad form).

Comment: Another question I have is: why people downvote without commenting? I'm still new to the site, I found something strange to me and wished to undesrtand better if it was a bug or if it is allowed .. it was told me to post a question to meta and people here helped me to clarify it perfectly .. so why the downvotes?

Comment: People downvote pretty liberally on meta, sometimes for no (apparent) reason.  That said, [voting is different here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences).

Comment: Meta's a dangerous neighborhood, what with all the drive-by downvoting and such.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doesn't look like a bug. You *are* allowed to [answer your own question](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/); see also [Can I answer my own questions, even those where I knew the answer before asking?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/can-i-answer-my-own-questions-even-those-where-i-knew-the-answer-before-asking)

If you find out something cool you think other people will be interested in and want to share it, you can't just post that fact as a question because this is not a blog. You *can* however ask the question you already know the answer to and answer it yourself. In this case it worked out great for the OP because both question and answer received hundreds of upvotes.

Comment: Your link helped me a lot to understand better how things are intended to work in those cases! :)

Answer (score 6):

The OP of the question you linked to [has spoken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-bash-shell-script#comment12781305_59839)!

> No error in the code, I asked the question, and answered immediately.
>   I initially searched StackOverflow for an answer, didn't find it,
>   figured it out from elsewhere, then returned to StackOverflow to ask
>   and answer, so people could find it in the future. – [Grundlefleck](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4120/grundlefleck) [11
>   mins ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-in-a-bash-shell-script#comment12781305_59839)

Grundlefleck had a problem, solved it, and made sure that SO has that solution for future generations.  From the votes, it looks like this user has helped out a bunch of people in the process.

So, it appears the system is working as intended =)

Comment: That post is an absolute rep _gold mine_.

Comment: Yeah, about 20/day at least